# How to integrate with Paypal suggested solution: "Add payment buttons to your website"

Tags: paypal, web, payment

I hope to integrate Paypal using "Add payment buttons to your website" https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/ since my site only needs one time purchase so this solution is perfect.

But it requires an IPN implemented as an async solution at the merchant side to receive the transaction result.   While the button redirects user to paypal.com to finish the payment process. But after that is done.  User is not automatically redirected back to merchant site.

I found on the forum that I can add an "data-return" attribute in the script element so when user is done paying there is an additional link that points to the merchant site.  Now since IPN is asynchronous, once user views the "data-return" page, IPN may not have been called yet.  My questions are:

```
1. So what's the suggested solution of synchronizing between return page and IPN?
2. When testing, I found a lot of query strings are appended to the "data-return" URL, looks related to transaction result.  Can I use them to replace IPN so I have a SYNCHRONOUS way of verifying the transaction result?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Payment Data Transfer (PDT, for short). https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/